# Does Dart aim to replace Haxe in terms of compiling to non-dart targets?

Tags: dart, haxe

Does Dart aim to accomplish a lot of the same functionality as Haxe in terms of being able to target other languages and runtimes?  Is it a stated or known goal of the language & tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Dart is aimed specifically at web application development (even more specifically, client-side web development, at least until 1.0, at which point more focus may be spent on fleshing out server side development). Dart supports transpilation to JavaScript by necessity, but the goal is not to be a multi-platform language like Haxe.

There have been proof of concepts running Dart VM on Android, and this may be a feature in the future, but this is not a stated goal of the Dart team at this point in time.

Sources:

http://news.dartlang.org/2013/05/dart-project-co-founders-answer-your.html Question 1
https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/TjHs5Fj5s50 Post by Shailen Tuli

Comment: Great answer, thanks!  I assume however that if dart continues to mature, it could one day challenge haxe in terms of target support.  I'm seeing jdart and other compilers out there.  Seems inevitable?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there will be plenty of interesting work done in this area (there's even someone working on a [dart2haxe transpiler](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/misc/H6QLSFtz04c/yD0asX85j7gJ)) but I assume it will remain the work of third-party developers, as opposed to ever becoming an explicit mandate of the Dart project.